# 3d algorithm - Sort multiple of 4 grid, into subsequently smaller quads

Tags: algorithms

I’m working on a custom exporter for a 3d project.
I have groups of faces (quads) that are always multiples of 4, each quad could be further subdivided into another group of 4, but in the editor they are all part of the same mesh/group (no parent/child).

I would like to export these quads by iterating through the “supposed” parent quad and going down until there are no more multiples of 4 to “encapsulate”.

So for example, if the following picture, the whole mesh would be the parent quad, then I would like to group first the red quad, then the green one, then the blue one and finally the yellow one.

[image]

I can iterate through the vertex indices of the grid and retrieve the ones that are not duplicated, so then I can check which quad is in the corner, so I can pick one of those quads to start this process.

Once I have that quad I can compare the center point of this quad with the other quads and determine for example which one is closest to the right, and then bottom for those two and that would be the first subgroup.
But that approach has many issues, depending on which corner I start first and which quad I pick after I’m done with each group

There must be a cleaner and simpler solution but I cannot think of any.

Does anyone have any suggestions or hints for a different approach?

EDIT:
To clarify a bit, what I want to achieve, it is a kind of LOD system. For example, for the mesh in the picture, from far away I will render just a big quad using just the vertices of the corners, then as I get closer then I will render only the 4 coloured quads and so on. To do so I need to have the information store in such way, and I would need an algorithm to automate that.

Comment: I did not understand the problem. Are you trying to create a hierarchical tree? I did not understand this statement: "I can iterate through the vertex indices...."? and the paragraph after that. What kind of operations you want to perform?

Comment: I guess in a way it could be considered an hierarchical tree.
Want I want to achieve, it is a kind of LOD system. For the example mesh in the picture, from far away I will render just a big quad using the vertex of the corners, then as I get closer then I will render only the 4 coloured quads and so on. To do so I need to have the information store in such way, and I would need an algorithm to automate that